# Cannot get line to use style file but works fine with polygons. Any idea why?

Tags: qgis

I'm using the UKHab symbology (style file downloaded from the UKHab working group). It works fine when assigned to the polygon shape file but when I try to assign the symbology to the line shapefile it doesn't work. The lines disappear leaving only the vertices visible. My QGIS knowledge/experience if pretty basic so any help would really be appreciated[image]

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen. Also, details on your symbology would be helpful.

Comment: Screenshot added. The two vertices in the middle to the redline boundary is my 'hedgerow'. Th Eline has disappeared leaving only the vertices showing, and yet I have got the style file loaded, using the correct 'value'. I've also added a screenshot with the polygon shape file showing to illustrate that the style file works with that.

Comment: Please provide more details on the exact symbology. Currently I can't make out how exactly you're trying to style your line. Is it a marker line, or a line, or an arrow, or ... ?

Comment: Line and polygon have different styling setting, are you sure you are using a style mean to be used with line ?

Comment: This I'm not sure of now - I wasn't aware that lines and polygons used different style settings. The style file I'm using is downloadable from https://www3.ecountability.co.uk/ukhabworkinggroup-ukhab/ and has been designed to be used with QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

As I know the symbology are different depending on the geometry. You will not be able to apply the line layer styles on a polygon layer and vise-versa.

1. Copy-Paste Styles:

[image]

2. Exporting then loading styles

[image]

[image]

The solution in your case would be to convert those lines to polygons using the "Polygonize" processing tool which would convert those lines to polygons then you would be able to apply that specific style (provided your lines close).

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I shall give that a go.